# Combining 2 google sheet formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I have:

- this formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(G4:G1000&""&H3:K3&""&H4:K1000);""))`
- this formula `=QUERY(M4:O1000; "select M,N,O WHERE O is not null")`

I have some horizontal data that I need for it be vertical

```
ID      Compensation    Fee     Reimbursement   Interests
12345   1863                    750
```

And the 1st formula does that

```
ID      Category        Amount
12345   Compensation    1863
12345   Fee 
12345   Reimbursement   750
12345   Interests
```

But, as you can see, it also has rows without amounts and I don't want that.
That's when the second formula is used, to remove those, and it does a query based on the output of the 1st formula.

Ideally, I would achieve this in one formula but every time I try to combine them, I break it. I'm sure this is quite obvious for many, but I can't seem to do it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(G4:G1000&""&H3:K3&""&H4:K1000);"";0;0);"where Col3 is not null"))

Comment: MattKing, thank you. I was assuming I would have to have select, then I just kept messing up the formula. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

```
=let(Σ,reduce(wraprows(,3,),sequence(counta(G4:G)),lambda(a,c,{a;{tocol(wraprows(index(G4:G,c),4,index(G4:G,c))),tocol(H3:K3),tocol(index(H4:K,c))}})),
       filter(Σ,index(Σ,,3)<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: I'll for sure dig into it. It has a lot of things with which I'm not familiar with so I will have to do some research to better understand. Thanks!